# Powershell to get file written in last 2 days

Tags: powershell, date

I have the following code to find score files that are newer than 2 days from today (2/16 - 2/18). The files are dated 2/15/2021 and 2/17/2021 and today is 2/18/2021. So I would expect this to give me one file name but it return 0 file names. I can see in the ([System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show(($date1))) line that it outputs 2/16/2021 and the time I ran it which is what I want. Any ideas?

```
    try{
Get-Process mame64 -ErrorAction Stop
$date1=$(get-Date).AddDays(-2)
Get-ChildItem -Path D:\HyperSpin\Emulators\Mame\hi | Where-Object {$_.LastwrittenTime -ge $date1} | Out-File -FilePath D:\HyperSpin\Emulators\Mame\Hitxt\Hiscoregames.txt
([System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show(($date1)))
$game="frogger.hi"
Start-Process -FilePath D:\HyperSpin\Emulators\Mame\Hitxt\hi2txt.exe -WorkingDirectory D:\HyperSpin\Emulators\Mame\Hitxt -ArgumentList "-hs D:\HyperSpin\Emulators\Mame\plugins\hiscore\hiscore.dat -r D:\HyperSpin\Emulators\Mame\hi\$game -max-lines 3" -RedirectStandardOutput D:\HyperSpin\Emulators\Mame\Hitxt\Process.txt}
catch{
([System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show('Yikes'))}
```

Comment: Typo.. `$_.LastwrittenTime` --> `$_.LastWriteTime`

Comment: OMG that was totally it!!! I wonder why it didn't produce an error?! TY!

Comment: May I also suggest you create the compate date using `$date1=(Get-Date).AddDays(-2).Date`. this will set it to midnight by zeroing out the time part.

Comment: Autocomplete is your friend, well my friend anyways.